# Filtering dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have details for a booking to be entered. The user will enter their Booking Date and Time and then select an employee for their booking. I want this app to work so that , when a user selects a Date and Time , the drop down list for employees must auto filter for those employees that are available. I have a status for the Booking , to be "On Going or "Complete". At the moment if there are 2 employees , Jack and John. If Jack is busy at 1pm, we can choose John. But if Jack is busy for 1pm , we cannot choose Jack for 2pm, we can only choose John throughout. Please see my code below 
On Going - means that the Booking is not complete , so the employee on this booking cannot be selected for other bookings. If a Booking is On Going at 12 pm, the employee allocated for this booking cannot be selected for other bookings at 12pm.
Complete - means the booking is complete, and the employee is now available.

```
 BookingContext db = new BookingContext();
    // GET: Home
         public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "EmployeeName");
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetEmployees(DateTime BookingDate)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        List<Booking> timeBooking = db.Bookings.Where(x => (x.BookingDate == BookingDate|| x.BookingDate != BookingDate) && (x.Status!="On Going"||x.Status==null)).ToList();
        var EmpList = (from d in timeBooking
                       join e in db.Employees on d.EmployeeID equals e.EmployeeID

                        select new { e.EmployeeID, e.EmployeeName }).ToList().Distinct();
       // var EmpList = (from u in db.Bookings where u.BookingDate != BookingDate && u.Status == "On Going" select u).ToList();
        //List<Booking> EmpList = db.Bookings.Where(x => x.CountryId == CountryId).ToList();
        return Json(EmpList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
}
```

}

```
 @model SkillScheduling.Models.Booking

 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

 <h2>Index</h2>

 <div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookingDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookingDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookingDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

</div>
```

```
 <div class="form-group">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeID, new SelectList(" "), "--Select Employee--", new { @class = "form-control" })
 </div>

 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#BookingDate").change(function () {
        $.get("/Home/GetEmployees", { BookingDate: $("#BookingDate").val() }, function (data) {
            $("#EmployeeID").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $("#EmployeeID").append("<option value='" + row.EmployeeID + "'>" + row.EmployeeName + "</option>")
            });
        });
    })
});
 </script>
```

Comment: `(x.BookingDate == BookingDate|| x.BookingDate != BookingDate)` <= this will always be true

Comment: `(x.Status != "On Going" || x.Status == null)` <= you don't need both of these conditions, since `null` does not equal `"On Going"`, you can remove the `x.Status == null` part.

Comment: I think you need to at least be able to describe the rule you're tyring to enforce in code before you start writing the code. You've stated, *"if there are 2 employees , Jack and John. If Jack is busy at 1pm, we can choose John. But if Jack is busy for 1pm , we cannot choose Jack for 2pm"*, which does not adequately describe any rule. Please update the question with the *specific* rules for choosing the employees. It's not exactly clear what "On Going" and "Complete" mean, either (at least to me).

Comment: Thank you I have edited the question

Comment: You want to find out who's available, given a timespan for an event, and various timespans for people? I think you want to do the opposite of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453381/check-if-date-range-is-within-another-date-range-for-fullcalendar-io-display/53453455#53453455